# Adding Macro Action via VBA resets Animation Timeline

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a shape which has an entrance animation and runs the following macro when clicked:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(m).Shapes("XYZ").ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionNone
    .AnimateAction = True
End With
```

Once I click the button, it disappears and the animation is reset. I need to click 'next' in the presentation view for it to enter the slide again.

I tried removing the line `.AnimateAction = True` but that didn't yield any positive result. I tried `.Visibility = True` but the shape was visible, the slide had just reset all animation.

How do I **remove all macros** associated with that button on it's click but also make sure that **animation timeline is not reset**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Call SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoClick(msoClickStateAfterAllAnimations)`

Let your animation timeline reset. Then let all animations play.

Comment: This does solve the issue but the animation seems to be stuck. I have a timer of a 10 second wipe animation. That seem to be stuck at that moment. Any chance to let that play?